# copy folders and content to a external drive

Tags: batch, xcopy

i have this

```
for /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /ad "*"') DO ( FOR /F %%c IN ('dir /b/s "%%a\*.txt" ^') DO XCOPY "%%a" "J:\" )
```

but it only moves the files inside each folder like this

```
[source]
D:\
  folder1
     test1.txt
  folder2
     test2.txt
[destination]
J:\
  test1.txt
  test2.txt
```

How do I get the destination to be this

```
J:\
  folder1
     test1.txt
  folder2
     test2.txt
```

Edit: source and destination are on 2 different drives if that helps.

Comment: Please state your actual problem: describe what result do you exactly want to achieve, rather than typing a (rather complicated to analyze at first glance) command that does something and asking how to fix it.

Comment: By using the /f argument you're telling FOR to only look at files. You'll need to start with that. What else are you trying to do with that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. If you are trying to copy a directory recursively (preserving its structure and the files within), the following should work fine:

```
xcopy d: j: /s /e
```

Comment: bruh way overcomplicated Thank you KISS(Keep It Simple Stupid) lol